# Lua equivalent to Python's Multiprocessing?

Tags: lua

In some Redis loading tests, LuaJIT 2.0 (beta) is performing quite nicely, at about 60% of the runtime of a similar single threaded Python script.

When using Python's multiprocessing module to [chunk large text files](http://www.ngcrawford.com/2012/03/29/python-multiprocessing-large-files/), results in a significant performance improvement splitting the works across cores.

I am assuming using the same approach in Lua would perform even better, but as a Lua beginner, I have not found the correct approach. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [LuaThreads](http://medek.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/lua-threads-and-stuff/), however, as explained [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-04/msg00222.html) by Mike Pall, it isn't really the best solution for multi-threading and interlinked task (as all threads will hammer the single lock on the lua state).

However [LuaLanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/) may provide what you need, but, seeing as you are using/favorable to LuaJIT and not just plain Lua, you can probably leverage the FFI to spawn system threads straight from LuaJIT and pass them a Lua callback (I'm not sure on the safety of this however, thats something for the LuaJIT mailing list).